# ComObject alternative for the New Outlook Preview app

Tags: outlook, office365, office-automation, com-automation, new-outlook

Our organisation is migrating to Office 365, this means mail will be available via Exchange Online so user can access there mail via the webbrowser but also via the "New Outlook Preview" app in Windows 10/11.

A suggestion that has been made is to stop working in the old Outlook 2016 desktop app. But this brings implications with so automation apps. For example there are some (CRM) apps that use the Desktop Outlook Comobject in order to open a new mail in the user mailbox and prefill it with (HTML) content. As far as i know this isn't supported with the "New Outlook Preview" app. Alternative was to rework this to `MailTo` functions, but these don't support HTML body's (and we need it)

Does some of you out there have the same problem and how did you fixed it?

**Update 2023-07-14**
Due to some tips and hours of searching on the internet i have two workable solutions. Not ideal but they come close as a replacement of the Outlook COM object.

1. Mailto and clipboard
   This one was the easiest. I use the `MailTo` protocol to open Outlook with a new draft mail, prefilled with To and Subject. Then i style a HTML as a string and then put it on the clipboard (in C#) telling the clipboard it has HTML as data. Now the user only has to put the cursor in the body and hit Paste. Voila done! Two downsides are:

- Not having option to apply attachments
- User forgets it has a pre styled body on the clipboard

2. Graph API
   I managed to create a draft including HTML body and attachments. It even returns a `deeplink` where you can open de draft directly in the web browser. This also has two downsides for me:

- The link is opened in the default webbrowser and not in the new `outlook preview`
- The user has to click edit in order to start working.
  There a lot of topics out there with deeplink URI scheme's in other to edit/compose a email in OWA but non of them work. Due to the lag of documentation i wasn't able to get this to work.

Hopefully MSFT keeps working of "One /Monarch Outlook Preview" for desktop to enrich it with automation functions...

Comment: vote for the feature: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/21fea1cd-ec1f-ee11-a81d-0022484cae1d

Answer (score 2):

Do not stop using the desktop version of Outlook. The new Outlook is a replacement for Windows Mail and Calendar, not for the desktop version of Outlook (which is part of the Office suite).

Comment: i hear you, but on another level they decided if it's not needed anymore it saves licenses and maintenance and therefore costs... Also de UI it pretty much the same as the web version except that you have local prefinals you can use which is a bonus and it helps the user experience because it looks the same everywhere.

Comment: Well, I've seen this story play out many times before :-) It then turns out some must-have features are missing and the LOB apps that the company relies on stop working...

Comment: It's a never ending story ;-)

Comment: *"The new Outlook is a replacement for Windows Mail and Calendar, not for the desktop version of Outlook (which is part of the Office suite)."* I sincerely hope you're right, but I'm not sure Microsoft agrees. I still remember the "Try the new Outlook" toggle that suddenly appeared on all Outlook desktop clients a few months ago...

Comment: @Heinzi - from the PM point of view, consolidating 6 different codebases is very tempting, but leaving countless corporate customers who use COM addins or OOM LOB apps high and dry is a no-go. They can probably cut it off when they decide that the number of pissed off customers will be low enough, so the question is when the two balance each other out. IMHO that will be years given how slow most companies move when it comes to rewriting/deprecating apps that work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook for desktop is still a part of the Microsoft Office package and is not going to retire in near future. So, you may continue relying on the COM automation technology.

However, there is no other trivial way to compose items with HTML bodies and then show to users with a project Monarch (new Outlook). Since you are using a web browser you can provide a form on the web page to create the email. On the backend side you can use the Graph API for that. See [Outlook mail API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview) and [Explainer: How does the Microsoft Graph API send mail?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-things-to-know-about-send-mail) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed info! Would it be possible to compose a mail with HTML body without sending it directly so the user can still edit it with the Graph API?

Comment: You can create a draft and save it to the folder.

Comment: And how would one open the draft as a new message? In the meantime i have been looking into alternatives. One would be to use a MailTo and then copy the text as an HTML object to the clipboard. Then a user can paste it into the email and voila! Another solution would be EML files but those are not yet supported....

Comment: The Graph API option isn't a solution if your application is intended for many customers - because you would need admin access to every customer's 365 tenant to set it all up.